# Melt on first level of multiindex, keep second level as column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, with a multi index (date, category) on certain columns:

```
|       | 1.2016 | 1.2016 | 1.2016 | 1.2016 | 1.2016 | 2.2016 | 2.2016 | 2.2016 | 2.2016 | 2.2016 | Unnamed: 0_level_1 | Unnamed: 1_level_1 | Unnamed: 5_level_1 | 
|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------| 
|       | foo    | bar    | turtl  | truck  | phon   | foo    | bar    | turtl  | truck  | phon   | Unnamed: 0_level_0 | Unnamed: 1_level_0 | Unnamed: 5_level_0 | 
| PIZZA | 4      | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 9      | 10     | 11     | 12     | 13     | 424242             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | 
| PIZZA | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 9      | 10     | 11     | 12     | 13     | 14     | 424243             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | 
| PIZZA | 0      | 1      | 2      | 3      | 4      | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 9      | 424244             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | 
| PIZZA | 3      | 4      | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 9      | 10     | 11     | 12     | 424245             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15 

            |
```

The other column have an empty multiindex, but I would like to keep them.
I would like to melt my dataframe (well, melt seems to do something close to what I want) to basically have this kind of entries:

```
|         |     |       |       |      |        | Unnamed: 0_level_1 | Unnamed: 1_level_1 | Unnamed: 5_level_1 |       | 
|---------|-----|-------|-------|------|--------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|-------| 
|     foo | bar | turtl | truck | phon | date   | Unnamed: 0_level_0 | Unnamed: 1_level_0 | Unnamed: 5_level_0 |       | 
|     9   | 10  | 11    | 12    | 13   | 2.2016 | 424242             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     10  | 11  | 12    | 13    | 14   | 2.2016 | 424243             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     5   | 6   | 7     | 8     | 9    | 2.2016 | 424244             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     8   | 9   | 10    | 11    | 12   | 2.2016 | 424245             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     4   | 5   | 6     | 7     | 8    | 1.2016 | 424242             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     5   | 6   | 7     | 8     | 9    | 1.2016 | 424243             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     0   | 1   | 2     | 3     | 4    | 1.2016 | 424244             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA | 
|     3   | 4   | 5     | 6     | 7    | 1.2016 | 424245             | TOP_PIZZA          | 15                 | PIZZA |
```

I tried to modify the `col_level`parameter to 0 or 1, but I never end up with what I want. I also tried to pass the columns of the first level to the `value_vars`parameter, but no success there either.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you not just `.unstack()` ?

Comment: Not really. I simplified my question. I actually have more columns that I didn't show, like "farm_location" and other, which are also multiindex. In my example the first column also has a multiindex, unlabeled. If I unstack, I unstack these columns as well.

Comment: Then you need to provide something people can work with, with your caveats like that - otherwise, people are going to waste time pointing out answers that you know can't work, but they don't because you haven't mentioned such things... Please [edit] your question to be representative of what you actually have please...

Comment: OK I edited my question to provide more details about my tricky situation